# Jenkins Email Extension plugin not working properly after latest Jenkins update 2.277.3 LTS

Tags: jenkins, groovy, email-ext

Email Extension plugin failing to send emails with the content of Jenkins environment variables after the Jenkins update from 2.263.3 LTS to 2.277.3. Following how my configuration looks like

**Editable email configuration project level(picture attached):**

Project Reply-To List: $DEFAULT_REPLYTO

Content Type: HTML

Default Subject: $DEFAULT_SUBJECT *which is $PROJECT_NAME - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS!*

Default Content : ${SCRIPT, template="email-template.groovy"}

[image: Editable-email-config-project level]

**After successful build I am getting email like below (picture attached).**

I am not sure why I am getting email with variable names but not with its content.It was working perfectly before Jenkins upgrade. Any help appreciated.

[image: email]

Comment: were you able to resolve this?